# Как исправить такую ошибку JavaScript?

Tags: jquery, html5, javascript

Привет всем, есть вот такая html страница:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Вывод общей длины и времени пути с учетом пробок - добавление маршрута на карту - API Яндекс.Карт 2.х</title>

<script src="http://yandex.st/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="http://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.0/?load=package.full&lang=ru-RU"
            type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">    
        var myMap, route;

        // Как только будет загружен API и готов DOM, выполняем инициализацию
        ymaps.ready(init);

        // Определяем местоположение пользователя на карте с помощью HTML5 
        // GeoLocation API
        // Почему-то не работает!!
        function init () {

            if(navigator.geolocation) {

                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                    var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
                    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

                    var  myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
                        center: [latitude,longitude],
                        zoom: 16
                    });

                myMap.controls                
                    .add('zoomControl')                
                    .add('typeSelector')                
                    .add('mapTools');

                var myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([latitude,longitude], {
                    }, {
                        preset: "twirl#redIcon"
                    });
                // Добавляем метку в коллекцию
                myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);      
            });
            } else {
                alert("Geolocation API не поддерживается в вашем браузере");
            }
        }

        function init () {
            myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
                    center: [49.98, 36.22],
                    zoom: 12
                });

                //Добавляем элементы управления    
             myMap.controls
                // Кнопка изменения масштаба
                .add('zoomControl')
                // Список типов карты
                .add('typeSelector')
                // Кнопка изменения масштаба - компактный вариант
                // Расположим её справа
                .add('smallZoomControl', { right: 5, top: 75 })
                // Стандартный набор кнопок
                .add('mapTools')    
                //Линейка масштаба
                 .add(new ymaps.control.ScaleLine())
                 //Обзорная карта, с заданным типом
                 .add(new ymaps.control.MiniMap({
                    type: 'yandex#publicMap'
                }));

         $('#search_route').submit(function () {                
            var start = $("#start").val();
            var end = $("#end").val();            
            ymaps.route([
                   // Список точек, которые необходимо посетить
                   [start], [end]], {
                // Опции маршрутизатора
                mapStateAutoApply: true, // автоматически позиционировать карту        
                avoidTrafficJams: true,    
            }).then(function (router) {
                route && myMap.geoObjects.remove(route);
                route = router;
                myMap.geoObjects.add(route);
                $("#resmarshrut").append('Общая длина маршрута: '+route.getHumanLength());
                $("#time").append('<br /> Время в пути: '+route.getJamsTime()/60+' мин.');

            }, function (error) {
                alert("Возникла ошибка: " + error.message);
            });
                return false;
            });
         }    
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="search_route">
<b>Начало: </b>
<input id="start" type="text" tabindex="1" value="Харьков, " placeholder="Харьков, ул. Героев Труда 37-А" autofocus autocomplete="on" style="width: 200px;"><br>
<b>Конец: </b>
<input id="end" type="text" tabindex="2" value="Харьков, " placeholder="Харьков, ул. Гаршина 9"  autocomplete="on" style="width: 200px;">
<input type="submit" tabindex="3" value="Найти">
</form>
<br>
<div id="map" style="width:400px;height:600px"></div>
<div id="resmarshrut"></div>
<div id="time"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Как мне исправить javascript код так, чтобы заработала Геолокация (HTML5 GeoLocation API)?

Comment: Вот ваш http://jsfiddle.net/fhc8p/. В коде почему-то две одинаковые функции init()..

Comment: Действительно, спасибо за подсказку. Видимо уже пора отдохнуть... Сейчас попробую объединить в одну функцию.

Comment: Вроде заработало, но если запускаю как html файл с рабочего стола, то пишет "Отслеживание Вашего местоположения этой страницей заблокировано". В чем может быть дело?

Comment: А дайте-ка новый fiddle

Comment: Только теперь проблема в том, что строится две карты, а мне нужна одна... Сейчас сделаю новый jsfiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Pwp6t/

Comment: Проблема в том, что строится две карты теперь, первая на которую накладывается маршрут, а на вторую накладывается геолокация. Как мне изменить код так, чтобы открывалась только вторая карта (с геолокацией) и на ней же прокладывать маршрут, введенный пользователем? Это вообще возможно или нет?

Comment: Геолокация не срабатывает на локальной машине, существует такое ограничение.

Comment: У меня все срабатывает даже если файл сохранен отдельно на раб.стол.

@eprivalov1, я там ссылку обновила..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну а если
[так](http://jsfiddle.net/fhc8p/2/)?

upd:
Обновила ссылку.

Comment: Ну как там дела?

Comment: Сейчас гляну, пять минут.

Comment: Так геолокация не срабатывает...

Comment: Может у вас в браузере геолокация запрещена. В скрипте, если геолокация не срабатывает, то центр устанавливается принудительно `center: [49.98, 36.22]`. А вы как хотели?

Comment: @eprivalov1: Геолокация работает, скорее всего как сказала @MyNameIs, она у Вас выключена, либо просто не поддерживается браузером. Каким браузером пользуетесь?

Comment: Google Chrome 30 версии...

Comment: Что-то мешает определить ваше местоположение. Попробуйте открыть страницу http://jsfiddle.net/fhc8p/2/ на другом компьютере и проверить.

Comment: Попробовал в Гугл Хроме, Яндекс Браузере, Мозилле - нигде не работает Геолокация. Хотя до этого в Мозилле работала 100%.

Comment: Проверьте, работает ли у вас геолокация - http://api.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/geolocation_ip. Может вы где что запретили..